# Memory, CPU, complexity tradeoffs for Python dict v. list with large 2D arrays

Tags: python

Suppose I have an approximately 1280 by 800 two dimensional array, and I want to be able to store approximately 4KiB of data in *some* array slots. (Maybe a couple of hundred?)

**What are the memory usage/CPU time/code complexity trade-offs for using a Python `list` or `dict`?**

A quick example for storing "blob.." at (123,456).

```
coord = (123, 456)
L = []
L[to_index(coord)] = "blob.."
# to_index() probably returns (456*1280) + 123
```

or

```
coord = (123, 456)
D = {}
L[coord] = "blob.."
```

Comment: Unless there is some specific details not outlined here, don't bother with a dictionary, it'll take more cpu, more space, to do the same as the array. Unless of course you're going to only store data in a fraction of those elements, then a dictionary *might* make more sense, but then a 1280x800 array of references occupies 8MB on a 64-bit platform, not a lot anyway.

Comment: Just the raw memory for the elements would be around 4Gb (1280 x 800 x 4096). I'm not sure you can get something reasonable...

Comment: That 4GB is the maximum, in practice not every cell will have anything. I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists won't be particularly efficient for storing this data, because you take no advantage in the fact that it's sparse. Basically you'd have to create a list of 1024000 elements, initially set to `None`. Internally it'd be a vector or 1024000 pointers, 8-bytes each on 64-bit system. Once this list is created, accessing and setting particular cell will be *O*(1) operation.

OTOH, dictionary is implemented as hash table. So you'll only need space for elements you've inserted. If you're dealing with sparse data it's better option. Inserts have amortized cost of *O*(1), access is obviously *O*(1) also.

You can read more about these datastructures in PyCon presentation ["Core Python Containers: under-the-hood" (PPT)](https://www.powershow.com/view1/d4649-ZDc1Z/Core_Python_Containers_powerpoint_ppt_presentation) (also available as [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYUsssClE94))

Comment: The link appears to be broken with a 404.